# using --http2.0 option with curl 7.33.0 gives unsupported protocol

Tags: linux, curl, http2, nghttp2

I am using centos 6.2, i needed to use curl --http2.0 in one of the server request, but i was having 7.19.6, after looking at http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html gives me that --http2.0 option is only supported with curl 7.33.0, so to overcome that problem, i have installed curl 7.33.0 by following the steps from http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/basicnet/curl.html
 after installing curl, i have tried to use that, but it is still giving me the error as **curl(1):unsupported protocol**, i have checked my curl version by using: **curl --version** this is giving me :

```
curl 7.33.0 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.33.0 OpenSSL/1.0.0 zlib/1.2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz
```

I needed to use this --http2.0 but not getting anything that how i could do that?
As curl 7.19 was installed and and i reinstalled curl with higher version, does this is making any problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained by Daniel [on the mailing list](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2013-09/0020.html):

> My plan is to base the http2 work on the nghttp2 library 
>   (https://github.com/tatsuhiro-t/nghttp2) [...] HTTP2 will start as a "feature" in libcurl terms and not specifically as a separate protocol.

So first of all you need to install [nghttp2](http://tatsuhiro-t.github.io/nghttp2/package_README.html#requirements) manually[1].

Then you need to explicitly enable HTTP2 support at configure-time with `--with-nghttp2`:

```
./configure --with-nghttp2=/path/to/nghttp2/install/dir [...]
```

[1]: at the time of writing the README states that it *is not packaged in Ubuntu, so you need to build it yourself*.

**EDIT**

*Please find below basic instructions to build the library only (not the command line tool) with default options.*

To build nghttp2 you first need to install its requirements (as detailed on [nghttp2 documentation page](http://tatsuhiro-t.github.io/nghttp2/package_README.html#requirements)):

```
# To clone the nghttp2 Github repo
yum install git

# Build essentials
yum install gcc
yum install make
yum install automake
yum install libtool

# Required to build the library
yum install pkgconfig
yum install zlib-devel
```

Once done clone the repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/tatsuhiro-t/nghttp2.git
cd nghttp2
```

Build the library as explained [here](http://tatsuhiro-t.github.io/nghttp2/package_README.html#build-from-git):

```
autoreconf -i
automake
autoconf
# Note: I assume you want to deploy it under /usr/local
# Feel free to adapt to your needs!
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
```

Then deploy it:

```
make install
```

If everything is OK you then need to build libcurl 7.33.0 by taking care to enable nghttp2 with `./configure --with-nghttp2=/usr/local [...]`.

**Extras**

If you want to build the application programs in addition (`nghttp`, ...) you would have to install additional packages before building nghttp2:

```
yum install openssl-devel
yum install libevent-devel
yum install libxml2-devel
yum install jansson-devel
```

Comment: i m not able to install it, can you give me step wise step all instructions to install it, as i m novice user to linux... thanks for support

Comment: if possible, give the instructions for other required software to support it

Comment: I've edited my question with nghttp2 library build instructions.

Comment: autoreconf -i is giving me error as:perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
 LANGUAGE = (unset),
 LC_ALL = (unset),
 LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
 LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C"). <br/> configure.ac:205: warning: macro `AM_PATH_XML2' not found in library  autoreconf: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1

Comment: Great! I've edited my answser once again with extra packages that may be needed (especially `libxml2-devel` that I assume you've installed to fix your configure error).

Comment: ya i have preinstalled that one