# HTTP2 with CURL gives "Unsupported Protocol"

Tags: curl, http2

Having already followed the steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116949/using-http2-0-option-with-curl-7-33-0-gives-unsupported-protocol), I still have `Unsupported Protocol` when using curl `--http2` option. Similarly, setting the `CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION` to `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0` results in the program communicating using HTTP/1.1, not HTTP/2.

Platform: Ubuntu 15.04 on VMware Player 7.

I have installed nghttp2-1.0.4 with `--prefix=/usr/local`, hence the libnghttp2.* is located in `/usr/local/lib`.

This is the code to configure curl-7.43.0:

```
./configure --with-nghttp2=/usr/local
```

The result shows that HTTP2 is enabled:

```
    HTTP2 support:    enabled (nghttp2)
```

After `make` and `sudo make install`, the following returns `Unsupported Protocol`:

```
curl --http2 https://http2.akamai.com
```

The curl version doesn't show nghttp2 is supported:

```
curl 7.43.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.38.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

Then I followed the advise from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759380/curl-is-not-working-with-nghttp2), that I need to have OpenSSL 1.0.2 or higher. Having installed that in /opt/openssl, I reconfigured:

```
./configure --with-nghttp2=/usr/local --with-ssl=/opt/openssl/lib
```

After `make` and `sudo make install`, all problems remain the same. Strangely enough, the `curl --version` still returns the same information as above, with OpenSSL/1.0.1f not yet upgraded.

Any help that allows me to successfully use the `--http2` option is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently you are not linking with the right version of curl, at least at runtime. That's what the output libcurl/7.38.0 means. Mine has a higher version number there. Try

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib curl <whatever>
```

as your command. Or just to be sure:

```
ldd `which curl`
```

and pay attention to the dependencies that appear listed.

Comment: The second command above shows that I'm still using the default library /lib/i386-liux-gnu. Setting the library path as the first code above fixed the problem. Curl is now speaking http2. Thanks!

Comment: As what was advised [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636536/install-curl-with-openssl), command `sudo` before `./configure`. Without `sudo`, mine didn't work.

Comment: I'm still having problems.
~~~~
autoreconf -i
automake
autoconf
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
sudo make
sudo make install
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib curl --http2 http://google.com
curl: (1) Unsupported protocol
~~~~

Comment: for mac os x, it will be ```otool -L `which curl` ```

Answer (score 3):

This one really helps me set it up properly

- git clone https://github.com/tatsuhiro-t/nghttp2.git
- cd nghttp2
- autoreconf -i
- automake
- autoconf
- ./configure
- make
- sudo make install

  - cd ~
  - sudo apt-get build-dep curl
  - wget http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.46.0.tar.bz2
  - tar -xvjf curl-7.46.0.tar.bz2
  - cd curl-7.46.0
  - ./configure --with-nghttp2=/usr/local --with-ssl
  - make
  - sudo make install
  - sudo ldconfig
    (to verify)
    curl --http2 -k -vvv -XPOST https://ip/
    https://serversforhackers.com/c/curl-with-http2-support

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it helped me install curl 7.46 with http2 support on Debian 8 today.

Answer (score 1):

I found [curl 7.53.1 for Windows](https://winampplugins.co.uk/curl/) this tool very useful to test the http2 requests.
It has pre-compiled builds of curl for Windows built with OpenSSL, ngttp2, zlib & IPv6 support.